# sql server: cannot replicate same order when creating tables

Tags: sql-server

When I run this code, it gives me different sorting results. When I manually do this in Excel, I always get the same results. Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
   select * into tblVSOELookupSort1 from tblVSOELookup order by 
   [SKU],[ASP Local],[Sum of Qty]
   alter table tblVSOELookupSort1 add RowID int identity(1,1) not null

   select * into tblVSOELookupSort2 from tblVSOELookupSort1 order by 
   [Region Per L/U],[Currency]

   drop table tblVSOELookupSort1
   drop table tblVSOELookup

   exec sp_rename tblVSOELookupSort2, tblVSOELookup

   select * from tblVSOELookup
```

Answer (score 0):

That's normal. SQL databases in general do not guarantee a particular row ordering of results unless you specify one. The order is dependent on the RDBMS implementation, query plan, and other things. If you want a particular row ordering in your query results, you must include an `ORDER BY` clause in your query. In this case, `select * from tblVSOELookup order by ...`.

Comment: Thanks for replying back. Is there any way of preserving the sort order by adding indexes or keys in the middle sorting tables?

Comment: No. Not reliably. If you care about order of rows you get back from a query, you must use `ORDER BY` in the final query you're reading your results from. Anything else will be implementation-dependent and prone to failure at some point.